# Algorithm for determining benefits of function memoization

Tags: algorithm, memoization, purely-functional, referential-transparency

**Problem**

Let's say I have some programming language with only referentially transparent functions. It's well-known that any of these functions can then be memoized. However, it's not always worth it in terms of time or space to memoize functions. *What is an algorithm for deciding whether or not it will save space or time to automatically memoize a function?*

**Example**

```py
# likely to benefit from memoization
def fact(n):
    return 1 if n == 0 else n * fact(n - 1)

# unlikely to benefit from memoization
def inc(x):
    return x + 1
```

**My use case**

I have a Lisp interpreter as a side-project, which restricts itself to a purely functional subset of Lisp. I want to memoize functions, but I don't want to blindly decide what should and should not be memoized.

**Additional info**

The solution could either operate using static code analysis, or it could operate during the lifetime of the program, or it could operate over several runs of a program.

The solution doesn't have to be perfect; it could just be a heuristic which is right a good amount of the time.

Comment: Hi Michael. I don't think this question is really answerable in the stack-overflow format -- there's too many trade-offs, heuristics, and dependencies on whole-program concerns (for example if you only call `fact` once, memoizing it is not cost-effective). Questions on s-o should have clear right/wrong answers.

Comment: @PaulHankin I'm afraid you're right. Maybe better for cs.stackexchange?

Comment: I'm not a regular user of cs.s-e, but I suspect you'll have the same problem there. Probably most helpful to you would be to find all related CS papers/work that discuss this problem (which I guess is a research area), but I'm not sure there's any online resource that makes this easy. Sorry!

Comment: Interesting question! One easy necessary-but-not-sufficient rule: The function must call itself recursively (possibly via a chain of other functions) to benefit from memoisation. You'll also need strong static analysis to determine the set of parameter combinations it will be called with (or, more likely, a sufficiently small superset thereof).  One thing that isn't a concern is termination: Although a "function" in a referentially transparent language may fail to be a total mathematical function due to nontermination on some inputs, memo(f) will terminate on all inputs for which f terminates.

Comment: This could actually be something where profile-guided optimisation can be usefully applied: instrument the function to record what sets of parameters it gets called with, run the program a few times, examine the stats and heuristically pick a set of parameter combinations to memoise in the next compilation/interpretation run.

Comment: For simplicity, I'd consider only functions whose parameters are tuples of integers, and limit memoisation to a single hypercube (product of intervals) in this parameter space... Memory used for the memo table is proportional to the hypercube volume, and there's probably a reasonably efficient way to find the "best hypercube" for a fixed volume -- that is, the hypercube of volume at most k bytes that contains the largest number of points, where each point is a parameter tuple that the function was called with.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yeah I think profile-guided optimization has gotta be the way to go because it's kind of impossible to tell with static code analysis how often a function will be called (halting problem and all that).